# Name of judaism.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I think most of us would agree that "mi.yodeya" was a snappy and memorable name. Is there any way to incorporate that into the site's present identity? WADR, directing your neighbor or co-worker to "judaism.stackexchange.com" just doesn't cut it. "Jewish Life & Learning" is better, but kind of bland, and does not correlate with the URL.

Perhaps the banner could read something like: "**Mi Yodeya:** Jewish Life & Learning on the Stack Exchange network." The mi.yodeya URL still points here, making access easy to the uninitiated (though I'm aware that alternate domain names are generally discouraged).

Thoughts?

Comment: FWIW, mi.yodeya.com points here, as do yodeya.com and miyodeya.com . Also, @mi_yodeya on twitter is still faithfully pumping out the questions feed.

Comment: I am in agreement that mi.yodeya is a great name. But for what it's worth, in my experience the burden and multi-syllabicity of the new name has not kept anyone interested from taking it down and visiting the site.

Comment: Again FWIW, I, for obvious reasons, am also a fan of the mi.yodeya brand name and would like to see it adopted here.

Comment: mi.yodeya is catchy and I feel that we should somehow get it back as our title.

Comment: @WAF - but will they remember it for more than 24 hours?

Comment: Re "I'm aware that alternate domain names are generally discouraged", I thought they're [encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/).

Comment: I like "mi.yodeya". "Mi Yodeya" also works, but I like it less. Still open to other suggestions, though, in the answers....

Comment: In the post here (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) I saw the following statement: "Due to a variety of practical difficulties with domain names, we prefer to de-emphasize domain name selection. Most sites will retain their topic.stackexchange.com names indefinitely." But upon further analysis I realize that this refers to the difficulties of coming to a consensus on an appropriate name. In our case, however, this should not be an issue.    LET'S GO MI.YODEYA.COM!

Comment: @msh210 SE [changed policies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/) about naming after the encouraging post you link to.

Comment: @Dave - I'll get back to you.

Comment: I'm not clear on what's being discusses here: a domain name or a title atop each page. Parts of the question ("directing your neighbor or co-worker to 'judaism.stackexchange.com' just doesn't cut it") imply the former, and parts ("'Jewish Life & Learning' is better") the latter. Can the question be made clearer, please? (My comment above, "I like 'mi.yodeya'", was assuming the latter, by the way: I meant as as the title atop each page.)

Comment: @msh210 - I am basically focusing on the practical (or "marketing") aspect: What do we call this site? Until now it was mi.yodeya, now it's ...? A site can cultivate an identity in multiple ways, URL being only one of them. My hope is that the Mi Yodeya name becomes an intrinsic part of this identity, to the extent that it appears as part of the title on the banner.

Comment: @Dave, I think what it's called in marketing should be what's on the banner, so people when they get here know they've come to the right place, unless it's a real URL (so mi.yodeya.com, not mi.yodeya), in which case people will know anyway that they've come to the right place. I think maybe the questions should be "what URL?" and "what banner?", with "what name to use in marketing" following therefrom naturally. But I'm not a marketing person.

Answer (score 13):

(OK, let's make this a little more formal. Community-wikifying for anyone who wants to add advantages.)

I nominate [mi.yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-does-mi-yodeya-mean) as the brand name for this site.

Advantages:

- Most (to date) of the content on this site came from a site with that name.
- Multiple mi.yodeya users and fans have approached me on- and off-line, expressing their disappointment with the name mi.yodeya going away.
- The name already has brand recognition within a segment of the online Jewish community.
- We already control the appropriate domain name and a mis-spell domain (miyodeya.com).
- It refers exactly to the thought going through the head of someone who's about to ask a question.
- It's immediately understandable to the acculturated population that this site is targeted at, much like "StackOverflow" is.
- It's also very recognizable to many, many, Jews, since it's a popular part of the most popular ritual in Judaism.
- The tails of the 'y's and the 'd' balance each other, making the title visually pleasing.
- I'm finding it quite awkward to refer to this site as "this site," "Judaism.SE," "judaism.stackexchange.com," or "the Judaism StackExchange site," depending on the context. "mi.yodeya" or "mi.yodeya.com" is much more convenient and identifiable.

Comment: It always comes back to the 'y' and the 'd', doesn't it?

Comment: @WAF words that please the eye so nicely don't come along every day. It's best to appreciate them when they do.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - Don't mind me. I was just joking.

Comment: @WAF We cool. @Everyone: Regarding the "How will people know how to spell it?" issue, how do people know how to spell yahoo, google, del.icio.us, or reddit? The word of mouth vector works when people like the site so much that they tell their friends about it. If they like it so much, they'll make it their business to provide the spelling.

Comment: +1 I also don't want the name to disappear

Comment: Mi.yodeya is not spelled very well. There's no 'yud' at the end of יודע so why is there a 'Y' there?

Comment: @Ariel See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/764/2 . The second 'y' disambiguates between segol and tzeireh and separates between the tzeireh sound and the immediately following patach sound. It seems to me to be the most unambiguous way to transliterate יודע  without punctuation.