# Name our chat room

Tags: discussion, chat, site-name

Right now, our general-purpose [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/jewish-life-and-learning) is called, excitingly enough, "Jewish Life and Learning." Some other sites have given their general chat rooms distinctive names, such as [The Garden Shed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/546/the-garden-shed), [Hub of Reason](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/311/hub-of-reason), and [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/mos-eisley).

What should our chat room be named?

Comment: Past discussion: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/chat-room-naming-discussion-installment-1

Comment: It would be helpful if you would identify which chat rooms belong to which sites...

Comment: @yydl, I thought it would be fun to make people guess.

Comment: @yydl, They're Gardening and Landscaping, Skeptics, and Science Fiction and Fantasy, respectively.

Comment: As per below, in the future I think it's best that you specify that there should only be one suggestion per answer. This way up-votes actually have meaning, and coming to a conclusion is much easier. Plus it just makes everything more clear on the part of the voter.

Comment: @yydl, Good points. Will do.

Answer (score 7):

Just my 2 zuzim:

1. Bais Midrash - a place where learning can be chatty.
2. The Yichud Room - it's just us, right?
3. The Shul - we shouldn't talk there, but so many people do.

Comment: Upvote is for #1. There is [no yichud](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1011/2) on SE, which we're happy about. And I'm opposed to promoting talking in shul.

Comment: David and @IsaacMoses, We shouldn't talk in shul, but kiddush is the time for socialization. How about "Kiddush Club"? :-)

Comment: @jake, Kiddush Club is brilliant!

Comment: @jake, please post an answer, so that it can collect votes on equal footing with other answers

Comment: @IsaacMoses, Within my other answer, or a separate one?

Comment: @jake, Given that we didn't get all formal from the beginning with "one name per answer", I'll leave it up to you.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/533/128), how about:

**Just my two zuzim**

or some variation thereof. I really like the "two zuzim" line. Very catchy.

Comment: How about just _t'rei zuzei_?

Comment: I'd go with My two zuzim. Very fitting for a chat room.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I got:

- **Daber Davar** (דַבֵּר דָּבָר). [Reminiscent of Yeshayahu 58:13.]
- **Tarbe Chachma** (תרבה חכמה). [A phrase from Bava Basra that, while not as much an implication of chatting as "Tarbe Sicha" like @msh210 suggested, doesn't have the same negative connotations.]

Or, following the whole "*sichah*" theme, we could use:

- **Shafachti Siach** (שפכתי שיח) or related form **Yishpoch Sicho** (ישפך שיחו). [From [Neila on Yom Kippur](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32573&st=&pgnum=258) and from Tehillim 102:1 respectively.]
- **Sichu B'chol** (שיחו בכל). [From Tehillim 105:2. Also, if spelled in English, could imply the double meaning שיחו בחול.]

Or, to be more *heimish*, we could go with typical places where multiple-person conversations go on in the Jewish world:

- **Kiddush Club**. [Although I think the OU has officially banned the conventional "Kiddush Clubs" that take place after Torah reading.]
- **Around the Chabura Table**. [For those that dig the group learning style over the one-on-one chavrusa style.]

Comment: +1 for _daber davar_ (or, actually, _v'daber davar_, whichI prefer). (_Tarbe chochma_ might be a better name for a page listing users' reputation-point counts. `:-)` )

Comment: Thanks @msh210. Can't believe I misspelled that.

Comment: Most of these are a bit too obscure, to my mind. The name doesn't have to be immediately meaningful to outsiders, but it should be to most of this site's usership.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, _v'daber davar_ [is in _kidush_](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11007).

Comment: @msh210, To be fair, I've never said, nor have I ever heard anyone say that part of kiddush.

Comment: jake and @IsaacMoses, oh... I have. Anyway, it's also used in discussions of _hilchos Shabas_, and _tarbe chochma_ is part of a commonly quoted proverb. _Sichu b'chol_ is in the daily prayers.

Answer (score 4):

Given that [mi.yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com) ("Who knows?") is an [unofficial name](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305/proposed-faq-language-explaining-mi-yodeya-references) for the main site, ani.yodeya ("I know!") could be a name for the chat room.

In [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=2657227#2657227), msh210 pointed out that this sounds a bit like it would be the answer part of the site, but given that there isn't a different part of the site dedicated to just answers (as opposed to questions and answers), I don't think there's much danger of confusion.

Comment: To be more inclusive, we could call it "Kulanu Yode'im", also a phrase from the hagadda, but perhaps not as recognizable. Also, it doesn't have that symmetry with the `y`'s and `d` that you seem to like.

Comment: I like http://ani.yodeya.com it makes it so much easier for me to reach chat whenever i want ^_^

Answer (score 2):

I like my [previously suggested](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/chat-room-naming-discussion-installment-1) "Tarbeh Sichah" (or "תרבה שיחה" or "Tarbe Sicha"):

- It's a quote from [*pirke Avos*](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90_%D7%94).
- It's a fitting description of a Stack Exchange chat room: when a comment section on the main site gets too long (between two people), [the software hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95937) that that area is not for "extended discussions" and that they should move it to a chat room.

Comment: 3) There are very few women here? :) (Seriously, wouldn't the negative connotation of the source be bothersome?)

Answer (score 2):

**מ' דבר** (Mi Deber, "who talks")

(Please forgive my hebrew-school, Ben-Yehuda Hebrew!) I like the idea of preserving the site's history in the name of the chat room (as Isaac [suggested](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/534/647)), and "Mi Deber" is thematically similar enough to "Mi Yodeya" to accomplish that.

Comment: Nice! I spun one off of this: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/625/2

Answer (score 2):

I like the Kiddush Club, so I'm posting as an answer.

**Kiddush Club**

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:

Beit Meidrash

30 chars

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by neilfein's [idea](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/624/2):

**Mi amar el mi?** = "Who said to whom?"

This question form may be familiar to many as a standard school exercise in Bible classes. It keeps the "Mi" name, like Neil pointed out. In addition, it represents a question that frequently comes to people's minds in chat when there are multiple threads of conversation going on at once.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite suggestion:

My Two Zuzim

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Let's shmooze

(or however you want to spell schmooze)

Comment: Not a big fan of this one, as _schmooze_ strikes me as one of those words that many non- or unaffiliated Jews associate with Judaism. A cliche of sorts. Compare [Dave's comment elsewhere](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/384/design-for-judaism-se/387#comment-869).

Answer (score 0):

How about the "Leitzanus Lounge"?

Comment: I was going to suggest "Moshav Leitzim" or "Yosh'vei K'ranos", but I thought the connotation (or probably actual denotation) was too negative.

Comment: Also, theres no warning in Tehillim to not join "Leitzanus Lounge". Mah she'ein kein moshav leitzim.

Answer (score 0):

Was going to suggest this, and despite seeing a similar answer, here goes:

**The Shteeble**

Answer (score -1):

All I can think of are really heimishe ones like:

- "the shteeble around the corner (you know, the one across from yossels place)" (or perhaps "the one with reb itche (or reb eiz'l) the gabbai" ;) @Isaac)

Comment: FTR, heimish as this place may be, eventually, the gabbaim are going to be elected ... I wouldn't name any part of it after someone in a temporary position.

Comment: @isaacmoses, I know, its just hard to imagine a j.se without eiz'l. IAE, then "the one with reb yoel on the board" sounds good.