# Final Vote to name Mi Yodeya's chat room

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat, site-name

We've had [a number of good suggestions](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/name-mi-yodeyas-chat-room) for [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468)'s name, and [the upvotes and downvotes on each](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/name-mi-yodeyas-chat-room) showed that there are five favorites (answers with net vote count greater than one standard deviation above the mean as of this writing, if you care). Here, you're being asked to vote among those five. They are:

A. **Chiddush Club** [(explanation and comments at the original proposal)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1103)
B. **Ta Sh'ma** [(explanation and comments at the original proposal)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1063)
C. **The Beit Midrash** [(explanation and comments at the original proposal)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1062)
D. **Sichas Chulin** [(explanation and comments at the original proposal)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1058)
E. **V'dibarta Bam** [(explanation and comments at the original proposal)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1056)

This vote will work as follows: Post as an answer to, or a comment on, this question the list of chat names you prefer, in order, with most-preferred first. Use the letters (A through E) above.

For example, if your favorite among the five is "V'dibarta Bam", your second favorite "Sichas Chulin", your third "Ta Sh'ma", your fourth "Chiddush Club", and your least favorite "The Beit Midrash", then you'd indicate your preferences by writing "EDBAC". That is your vote. (That is, "vote" in this post means indication of preferences, and has nothing to do with up/down arrows.)

(Please minimize comments and answers other than votes to the extent possible, so votes can be easily found.)

Your favorite will receive five points, your second favorite four points, and so on; your least favorite will receive a point. If you include only four options in your vote (e.g., you vote for ABDE), then your favorite will receive only four points, and down from there. Likewise, if you indicate only your favorite, it will receive only one point.

Duplicate votes by one user will not count (unless all but one are deleted).

All votes must be in by the close ([UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)) of May 22.

All points will be summed, and the option with the most points will be the new name for the chat room.

Comment: I'll start us off with **DECAB**.

Comment: I'll rotate yours to the left two: **CABDE** (Edited to add: I like how the character minimum is forcing us to add a little color text to our votes. :)

Comment: Isaac and I think similarly: __CABED__

Comment: How about **BECAD**?

Comment: Here's mine: **CDAEB**.

Comment: -and mine "**CABED** (es avicha v'es imecha)"

Comment: **EABDC** <------

Comment: **AEDBC** (no witty text to add)

Comment: **AEDBC** - My vote is cast.

Comment: How about **DCEBA**?

Comment: **EDCBA** Interesting that it's exactly in reverse order.

Comment: *****EADCB*****

Comment: @ه ه that you need 150 to vote in elections doesn't mean you need 150 to vote here. I included your vote in the ongoing tally. Now I'll remove it, because you deleted it, but if you vote again I plan to count it unless there's a mandate from the community to the contrary.

Comment: | @WAF Copycat.

Comment: **CEABD** for me

Comment: **CDBEA** is my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final scores, with 15 votes cast:

A: 3 * 5 pts. + 5 * 4 pts. + 2 * 3 pts. + 2 * 2 pts. + 3 * 1 pt. = 48

B: 1 * 5 pts. + 0 * 4 pts. + 5 * 3 pts. + 5 * 2 pts. + 4 * 1 pt. = 34

C: 6 * 5 pts. + 1 * 4 pts. + 3 * 3 pts. + 2 * 2 pts. + 3 * 1 pt. = 50

D: 2 * 5 pts. + 3 * 4 pts. + 4 * 3 pts. + 2 * 2 pts. + 4 * 1 pt. = 42

**E: 3 * 5 pts. + 6 * 4 pts. + 1 * 3 pts. + 4 * 2 pts. + 1 * 1 pt. = 51**

Comment: I independently came up with the same tally (though I only verified the math on A, C, and E.)