# What is the difference between twitter accounts?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, twitter

What is the difference between http://twitter.com/#!/StackJudaism/ and http://twitter.com/#!/mi_yodeya?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@StackJudaism is a feed [generated by StackExchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/) as a standard part of each SE site. It is fed automatically with "interesting questions every so often."

@mi_yodeya is an account I created back in the [mi.yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305/proposed-faq-language-explaining-mi-yodeya-references) days. I control it. The community uses it to tweet out timely Q&A on a daily basis. ([More detail is here.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1798/mi-yodeya-is-people))

Comment: So the latter has a fuller history of posts