# (How) should we re-purpose the mi_yodeya Twitter account to make it more interesting?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, twitter

**This post has been largely superseded by [this announcement](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1798/mi-yodeya-is-people). However, if you have new ideas for what we should do with the Twitter feed, please do post answers here.**

---

There are currently [two Twitter feeds](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/956/2) that automatically serve up links to Mi Yodeya and Mi Yodeya - Meta questions. One of them, [@mi_yodeya](http://twitter.com/#!/mi_yodeya), belongs to me<sup>*</sup>. I am (and apparently at least some other yodeyans are) [interested](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9970344#9970344) in switching this account from automatically sending out links to all questions to something manually curated, which will - hopefully - be more valuable and compelling.

If you have ideas for what it should do or how it should do it, please post answers to this question.

---

* I feel justified in taking a semi-unilateral approach to this account. I set up the account in the mi.yodeya 1.0 days, and after this site launched out of beta and officially took the name Mi Yodeya under Stack Exchange's auspices, I offered to cede control of it to either Stack Exchange or the community, as represented by the elected moderators. Neither party has yet chosen to accept this offer. As such, I retain the prerogative to do with the account as I will. However, I plan to use it in a way that is consistent with the will of the community whose name it bears, so opinions registered here will be important to determining how the account is used.

Comment: Followup question: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1798

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### My initial ideas:

#### What:

- A tweet or two, or at most a handful, per day, so that followers aren't inundated to the point that they tune us out.
- Primarily, tweets of links to MY content chosen to hook into topics that will be on people's minds already, such as this weeks parasha, today's daf, an upcoming holiday, or current events.
- Links should be accompanied by human-written text designed to attract interest to the content behind them.
- Tweets hashtagged appropriately to hook into ongoing Twitter discussions, e.g. #parsha, #pinchas, #dafyomi, #17tammuz, or #maharat

#### How:

- Set the account to be accessed by a free tweet scheduler, such as [HootSuite](https://hootsuite.com/).
- A small team of curators all have access to the scheduler account.
- Curators check the schedule and fill in tweets for the upcoming days so that there are one or a few tweets every day, spread throughout the day.
- Curators are also empowered to send non-link tweets as warranted to converse on the community's behalf with other Twitter users (as I very occasionally do now, along with the automatic barrage of links.)

Comment: Followup: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1798

Answer (score 2):

An implementation suggestion (presuming the general approach outlined in [Isaac's answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1736/472):

Preparation of tweets should be done by people who are familiar with the norms of Twitter, but that doesn't mean the rest of us can't help.  As with the haggadah project, we can separate *suggestions for content* from *actual production*.

People with suggestions can submit, either to a designated meta post or to a special chat room, links to interesting questions.  Each link should be accompanied by a word or two about its timing, e.g. "parshat Pinchas" or "daf Pesachim 7" or "Tisha b'Av".  Optionally, the proposer can add proposed tweet content.

Tweeters will review the suggestions, compose tweet text where needed, schedule, and mark links as "done".  On a meta post this means removing the link; in chat it means replying (since even room owners cannot edit or delete posts in chat).

It is up to the tweeters to determine the use, timing, and frequency of tweets; it is up to the community at large to make sure they are supplied with links to tweet.

I think the people who will be doing the tweeting get to decide where suggestions are collected and how they are managed.  They have to manage it; the rest of us just need a suggestion box.  There is room for experimentation, and we can always refine the process later if something isn't working well.

Comment: Rather than a wiki post, I think a dedicated chat room might be more appropriate. It would be continually bumped, and it doesn't become too unwieldy.

Comment: Isaac suggested a chat room today in Bam too.  My concern there is that it will be hard to track what's been used versus not, since non-moderators can't delete chat messages, but I'm certainly open to experimentation.

Comment: What if all the curators are made owners of that room? (Also, don't delete the messages, edit in a strikethrough.)

Comment: Room owners [apparently](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10078175#10078175) can't edit either. :-(

Comment: If we're willing to sacrifice strict track-ability, a chat room with acknowledgement signaled by a simple formal reply offers much lower overhead per tweet than a constantly-edited meta post (i.e. scrolling through the markdown, making sure to edit correctly, etc.) does. I'm less concerned about a suggestion getting used twice or missed than I am about the stream petering out because it's too much work.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I've edited to support either meta or chat, leaving the decision in the hands of the people who are actually doing the tweeting (since they're the ones who need to track it).  The main point of my suggestion was the separation of curation and tweeting, and I don't want to details of meta vs. chat to get in the way.

Comment: Followup: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1798