# @mi_yodeya is people!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, twitter

[image: Mi Yodeya icon]

The Twitter feed [@mi_yodeya](https://twitter.com/mi_yodeya) is now entirely human-run. We want to use it to promote Mi Yodeya content to a wider audience, using our God-given human intelligence to pick out material that's likely to be of people's interest now.

We'll be aiming to tweet at least once per (non-Sabbath/Festival) day, each time promoting one Q&A that may be especially interesting to people on that day. It may relate to one of the following:

- Weekly parasha
- Daf Yomi
- Upcoming holiday
- A story in the headlines
- Particularly awesome new content on Mi Yodeya
- [Project 929](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/shall-we-participate-in-the-929-studying-the-bible-together-project-how?cb=1)

If you want to enrich your Twitter stream with carefully-selected, high-quality Jewish Q&A, follow [@mi_yodeya](https://twitter.com/mi_yodeya).

---

Want to be one of the people behind @mi_yodeya? Here's how:

- Retweet us, of course!
- Give us constructive feedback on our tweets via Twitter or in our [chatroom for this purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10203/mi-yodeya-tweet-suggestions).
- [Suggest timely Mi Yodeya content to tweet.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1799)
- [Join the @mi_yodeya curator team.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1800)

---

<sup>@mi_yodeya is an unofficial effort by members of the Mi Yodeya community, including the author of this post, and is not run by the elected moderators (in that capacity) or by Stack Exchange, Inc. You can contact the project in private by direct-messaging [@mi_yodeya](https://twitter.com/mi_yodeya) on Twitter or by emailing yodeyans@gmail.com.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

#### Tweet Suggestions

To suggest Mi Yodeya content to be tweeted you don't have to know anything about Twitter. You just have to be interested in [searching](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search) Mi Yodeya for excellent content that is timely in some way (see [above](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1798)).

- Check out a general [Jewish Calendar](http://www.aish.com/jewish-calendar/Jewish_Calendar.html) to see what weekly parasha and holidays are coming up, or a [Daf Yomi calendar](http://www.dafyomi.org/machzor.php) to see what's coming up there. Or look at the [news](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=nws&q=jewish) to see what Jewish stuff the world is talking about.
- [Search](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search) Mi Yodeya for relevant (even if tenuously so) content, especially Q&A with particularly thought-provoking questions or informative answers.
- Go to the [tweet suggestions chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10203/mi-yodeya-tweet-suggestions), and drop a link to the Q&A you found, along with which date/parsha/etc. it relates to (when relevant).
- Optionally, feel free to add your own thoughts about why you like this Q&A, in particular.
- Don't worry about how, precisely, it'll be presented on Twitter. All you need to do is make the suggestion.
- Don't worry about duplicating someone else's suggestion. If worse comes to absolute worst, the same excellent content that multiple people like will be tweeted more than once. Not so bad.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

#### Tweet Curation Team

The @mi_yodeya tweet-curation team will be most sustainable if it grows a bit larger.

To apply to join, please email yodeyans@gmail.com or send a direct Twitter message to [@mi_yodeya](https://twitter.com/mi_yodeya).

Tweet curators will, on a weekly basis, if not more frequently:

- Log onto a shared [HootSuite](http://hootsuite.com) account.
- Scan the lists of @mentions, retweets, etc., to see if anything deserves a response. If so, tweet a response.
- Check the upcoming scheduled tweets to see if there are any non-Shabbat/Festival days in the next week that don't have anything scheduled yet. If so, try to come up with something to tweet then and schedule it.
- Visit the [tweet suggestions chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10203/mi-yodeya-tweet-suggestions) to see if there are any new suggestions. If so, decide whether to schedule them, and post a response in the chatroom acknowledging the suggestion and indicating what action was taken.

Thanks for taking initiative!