# Weekly Tanach Challenge 5775-3 (Week of Beshalach): Bereishit 26–30

Tags: discussion, weekly-topic-challenge, project-929

[In conjunction](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3349/2) with [Project 929](http://www.929.org.il/), let's learn Tanach along with Jews all over the world.

This coming week (Parashat Beshalach, starting Sunday, January 25), we'll be studying the following chapters:

- [Bereishit 26](http://sefaria.org/Genesis.26)
- [Bereishit 27](http://sefaria.org/Genesis.27)
- [Bereishit 28](http://sefaria.org/Genesis.28)
- [Bereishit 29](http://sefaria.org/Genesis.29)
- [Bereishit 30](http://sefaria.org/Genesis.30)

The challenge to you is: **study these chapters, and post questions about them, by the end of the week**. If you post a question in response to this challenge, please post a link to it in an answer here.

**Things you could win:**

- An Internet with more good questions and answers on Tanach.
- The experience of having learned Torah in concert with Jews around the world.
- Your question tweeted out by the [@mi_yodeya Twitter account](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1798/mi-yodeya-is-people).
- Your question [featured](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) on Mi Yodeya.

Come back here on Friday, January 30th, for a wrap-up of this challenge and the start of the next one.

Comment: I encourage you to post a standardized answer format either in the question or as the first answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA, is "Just copy the link to your question out of your browser bar and paste it into an answer." good enough?

Comment: Isaac and @DoubleAA -- are we looking for an answer like [this one](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/q/621/7282)?

Comment: @Shokhet I was thinking that the wrap-up could be part of next week's post or maybe edited into this one.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I guess it depends what you want to do with it. I was thinking more like: `**Genesis Chapter 20** (Week 20/929): http://mi.yodeya.come/q/XXXXXX/759 http://mi.yodeya.come/q/XXXXXX/759.` with one answer per chapter.

Comment: @DoubleAA Sounds like more overhead than is worth imposing on the would-be participant. Whoever puts the wrap-up together can do so with due structure.