# Name change of the Jewish site: Mi Yodeya

Tags: discussion, site-name

The name Mi Yodeya for the Jewish site concerns me from a usability standpoint, where finding this resource, if one isn't familiar with Hebrew, might only be discovered out of sheer luck. Other religious forums are simply called Christianity, Islam, Buddhism and Hinduism, and are therefore easy to find for knowledge seekers. My question is if the name can be possibly be changed simply to Judaism, or put to a vote, so that anyone who has minimal or no knowledge of Judaism can find it much easier. Seeking opinions on this.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/name-of-judaism-stackexchange-com

Comment: Just wanted to remind you that voting works differently on Meta - people downvoting are not saying your question is bad, they are just expressing they don't agree with it

Comment: Originally asked on Meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305097/162102.  What did you learn from the answer there?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I learned that I can't responsibly delete my question if someone has already answered it. It was suggested to me to post the question here, so I did, but it seems it's just as unpopular.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is already the case that this site is named "Judaism," in the sense that its primary domain name is http://judaism.stackexchange.com.

Anyone who sees that StackExchange has Christianity.SE, Islam.SE, etc. sites and is curious whether there is also a Judaism.SE is likely to discover Mi Yodeya via such means as:

- Trying the URL http://judaism.stackexchange.com
- Scanning through the list of Stack Exchange [Culture/Recreation sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation-traffic) until the word "Jewish" appears next to Mi Yodeya's six-pointed-star-shaped logo.

I don't think there's much danger of people who might be interested being unable to discover the site, under these circumstances.

Comment: Also, we have excellent search-engine placement when searching for information on Jewish topics using a variety of vocabulary.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with your concern in theory I don't believe the suggestion has merit in practice. If you google any host of terms related to "Judaism" + "Stackexchange" the Mi Yodeya site is the first result. Though it is fair to point out that someone not familiar with hebrew who sees that result may be confused at first, since the wording is not in Hebrew characters and the search results include an explanation of what the site is I don't think the usability problem is very compelling.

Furthermore the site has been around for many years so that changes to the name could actually have negative ranking and therefore 'discoverability' issues.

As mentioned in an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305098) to this question posed elsewhere there are other S.E. communities which have unique names so there is no naming convention that is being broken.

Answer (score 3):

When you search "Judaism" in the Stack Exchange community search, Mi Yodeya shows up.

[image]

I don't think it's a problem.